# Запятая после «то есть» перед союзом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**То есть где тонко, там и рвется.** Нужна ли запятая после "то есть"?

Answer (score 3):

[ТО ЕСТЬ](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_733), *союз и частица*

1. Союз. Присоединяет слова или предложения, поясняющие или уточняющие высказанную мысль; то же, что «а именно, другими словами». После союза «то есть» запятая не ставится.
   **2. Частица.** Употребляется для усиления эмоциональности высказывания, а также (в сочетании с «как») в ответной реплике для выражения недоумения, удивления, осуждения. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

**То есть где тонко, там и рвется.**

«То есть» не является вводным словом и не выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон — обычно запятая ставится перед ним.
Если же в каком-то контексте запятая ставится ***после*** «то есть», то совершенно по другим причинам: для выделения обособленной конструкции (например, вводного слова) или придаточного предложения, которые идут следом.
*До станции еще пять километров, **то есть, если идти не торопясь,** час ходьбы.*

[Запятые при словосочетании «то есть»](http://gramatik.ru/zapyatye-pri-slovosochetanii-to-est/)

**Дополнение** (после ответа и комментария), 26.11.2021
*По правилам запятая нужна — потому что придаточное можно переставить без нарушения структуры: То есть там и рвется, где тонко.*

Дело в том, что выражение *где тонко, там и рвётся* — это устойчивое сочетание, в нем ничего никуда переставлять не нужно.
Именно поэтому *то есть* в этом предложении, считаю, является не союзом, а усилительной частицей.
Именно поэтому запятая и не нужна.

Comment: А чем оличается употребление союза «где» от «если».. В одном случае без запятой, в другом с запятой...

Comment: _если идти не торопясь_ —это придаточное предложение, его можно "убрать" из предложения или переставить.1. До станции еще пять километров, то есть час ходьбы. 2. До станции еще пять километров, то есть час ходьбы, если идти не торопясь.

Comment: * Спасибо Вам, поняла)

Comment: А зачем говорить про запятую после "то есть"? Нужно говорить про запятую перед "где".

Comment: В смысле по каким-то? По общему правилу, которое вы прекрасно знаете. Или так: *То есть "где тонко, там и рвется".* Тут смысл однозначный, а вот посмотрите здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464069 После обнаружения этого как-то прибавилось уверенности...

Comment: Запятая иногда не ставится после союза, а если частица, наречие, то запятая должна стоять: *В любом случае, где тонко, там и рвётся. Также, где тонко, там и рвётся. Ведь, где тонко, там и рвётся. Ну, где тонко, там и рвётся.* Где правило, в котором указано, что частица может примыкать к придаточному?

Comment: *Ведь, где тонко, там и рвётся.* Вы считаете, что запятая нужна? ВЕДЬ. I. частица. Употр. для усиления основного содержания всего высказывания (предположения, утверждения, вопроса и т. п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова. *Ведь приди я вовремя, этого бы не случилось. Ведь поступи я иначе, всё обошлось бы.* (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C) То же усилительное значение. И примыкает.

Comment: Оно к главному относится не меньше, чем союз (придаточное можно переставить). Словари здесь не помощники: в некоторых примерах после "то есть" стоит запятая. Не удалось у Розенталя найти про это.

Comment: Хм, а без запятой другой смысл: *Ведь где тонко (а не как-либо по-другому), там и рвётся.* Вот так частица относится к придаточному. Оно не звучит по-русски. Надо как-то так: *Рвётся там, ведь где тонко.* Всё указывает на то, что запятая нужна. Так должно быть, если по-правильному (не по правилах — а в них, похоже, и нет об этом).

Answer (score 0):

По правилам запятая нужна — потому что придаточное можно переставить без нарушения структуры:
*То есть там и рвется, где тонко.*

Исключения есть лишь для союзов И, А, НО в начале предложения.