# Запятая после "то есть"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы, спп

***То есть(,) если хочешь стать испытателем, сначала поработай обычным лётчиком***.

Нужна ли запятая после союза "то есть" в данном примере? Согласно Розенталю, запятая может не ставиться после союзов "a", "и" и "но", стоящих в начале предложения. Но как обстоят дела с союзом "то есть"? В Нацкорпусе полно примеров и с запятой и без запятой, соотношение примерно равное. К слову, в этом конкретном предложении запятой не было. Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить ситуацию. Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/458898/183462).

Comment: Знаете, там я уже все посмотрел. Решить вопрос не помогло. Думаю, примеры из Нацкорпуса вполне демонстрируют, что тут не все всем очевидно.

Comment: У Розенталя написана лишь о присоединительных союзах, а в нашем же случае это не присоединительный союз, а поясняющий, значит, вероятно, запятая должна ставиться на общих основаниях.

Comment: @Игорь Болотов, в нац. корпусе примеры, в которых бы «то есть» обособлялось бы с двух сторон, крайне редки, 1-2 предложения на страницу, и все они объясняются обособлением последующих слов или сочетаний. «То есть, конечно, можно чего-то поправить.»(обособляемое вводное)  «То есть, если генератор случайных чисел выдаст для данного параметра 1, то происходит...»(обособляемое придаточное)

Comment: Я имел ввиду запятую на стыке союзов. Нужна ли она после союза "то есть" , если за ним идет подчинительный союз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Начнем с примеров:

**То есть, если** разобраться,  два раза знал он сам. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]
― **То есть, если** вы сыграете эту роль, ни у какого Станиславского не повернется язык вам сказать: не верю?! [К. Л. Селиверстов, 2011]

А также: **То есть**, взрослые ходят **в школу, а дети занимаются взрослыми делами**. [Алексей Слаповский. (1999)] **То есть**, монета не отскакивает. Более того, чем мельче монета, тем точней она ложится. [Фазиль Искандер (1980-1990)]

2. Я не вижу причин, по которым следует **запрещать** постановку запятой после союза ТО ЕСТЬ. Да, частотность здесь ниже; да, это пояснительный союз. Но здесь он используется в значении **присоединительного** союза.
3. Нет решения у Розенталя? Тогда надо **самим решить эту задачу**. У Розенталя запятая обычно не ставится после союзов И, А, но может ставиться после союза НО, а также чаще всего ставится после ОДНАКО.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140, пункт 5.

4. Почему? Вероятно, это влияние **фонетики**: выделить **ударением** эти союзы проще, чем союзы И, А. Что касается ТО ЕСТЬ, то он вообще состоит из двух слов, проблем нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122691/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).

Answer (score 3):

Мне думается, что ответ здесь очень прост, ведь речь идет о стыке двух союзов - "то есть" и "если". Как широко известно, на стыке двух союзов запятая ставится, если отсутствует вторая часть "то, так, но". Для проверки Розенталь предлагает изъять придаточную часть. Если структура предложения не нарушена, то на стыке союзов ставится запятая. Произведем изъятие из приведенного предложения. Получается: То есть... сначала поработай обычным лётчиком. Вывод однозначен: запятая на встрече двух союзов нужна.

Comment: Я думаю, для присоединительных союзов способ изъятия не подойдет, придаточное в этом случае практически всегда можно изъять. У Розенталя для таких союзов специальное правило: 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от ЗНАЧЕНИЯ союза.

Comment: Простите, но союз "то есть" никогда не был присоединительным союзом. Он известен как пояснительный союз, и изъятие вполне уместно

Comment: Розенталь не рассматривает ТО ЕСТЬ  в теме присоединительных союзов, но это  не значит, что функция присоединения для него запрещена. Союз И преимущественно используется как соединительный, но может быть пояснительным или присоединительным. Союзы А, НО , ОДНАКО – противительные, но бывают присоединительными (присоединительные конструкции вообще очень разнообразны).  А пояснительные союзы,  к примеру, используются после обобщающего слова при обозначении паузы перед раскрытием темы (как то, например). Разве  нельзя применить ТО  ЕСТЬ в той же функции – ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ о  последующем уточнении.

Answer (score 2):

Если запятая оказывается после "то есть", обычно на это есть *внешние* причины. Здесь запятая *нужна* перед "если" - для выделения *придаточного* предложения условия/причины (если/поскольку), которое находится ***внутри** главного*. По смыслу маловероятно, чтобы "то есть" относилось здесь к примыкающему придаточному, которое (начиная с "если") может быть переставлено в конец. Прояснить смысл может предшествующий контекст, который определяет, что именно поясняется через "то есть" - рекомендация "поработать" или её причина. Вероятен такой контекст:

> Испытателем сразу не становятся. ***То есть**, если хочешь стать
> испытателем, **сначала поработай** обычным лётчиком.*

В другом контексте по тем же семантическим причинам "то есть" может относиться к придаточному, тогда оно *полностью* окажется *перед* главным и второй запятой не потребуется:

> Чтобы стать обычным летчиком, достаточно окончить лётную школу. ***То
> есть только если** хочешь стать испытателем, поступай в эту академию.*

Answer (score 1):

**Второй ответ (по комментарию)**

Что делать, если вы **не нашли в правилах Розенталя** (или других правилах) ответа на свой вопрос? Вернее сказать, не просто не нашли, а считаете, что ответа там нет. К примеру, это наличие в практических текстах **вариативных форм написания,** в то время как разрешена к применению только одна форма. Что делать? Будете  править автора, считать, что это ошибка?  Я отвечаю на **этот вопрос.**

1. Практика письма может **обгонять** теорию письма (это мнение известных лингвистов). Меняется синтаксис, появляются новые формы. К примеру, тема с союзом **ТО ЕСТЬ.**  Возможно, она не была раньше актуальной, а сейчас появились варианты письма  и вопросы о том, как сделать правильный выбор. Поэтому задача теории – **обобщать практику**, анализировать и при необходимости корректировать правила, то есть давать достойный ответ на такой запрос.
2. Кроме того, **нельзя объять необъятное,** Розенталь не мог для нас решить абсолютно все задачи, но это не повод ля того, чтобы нерешенные формы запрещать. Мы можем решить задачу сами **по аналогии** и пояснить вариативное письмо.

**Давайте сравним с математикой.** Вот вам объясняют тему, дают решение типовых задач, называют принцип решения, а дальше уж сами. Это общий путь в любой науке: конкретное – обобщенное – конкретное. Смотрим представленные у Розенталя решения, пытаемся понять их принцип и применяем его к другим примерам, которые еще не решены.

3. По большому счету именно так и **действовал Розенталь**, ведь объем его правил значительно отличается от  Правил 1956 года, даже систематизация другая.  Но там на в конкретных примерах надо было **увидеть принцип** и применить его **на практике**. Именно такой метод и я применяю при  ответе на заданный вопрос.
4. Интересно, что позиция ТО ЕСТЬ **в начале предложения** может соответствовать обособленным вводным словам, причем союз и по значению близок **к теме вводных слов**, используемых **для оформления речи**.  Можно сравнить с вводными словами «итак, таким образом».  Но союз  при обособлении обозначает не вывод, а  **итоговое уточнение** ранее сказанного.

Answer (score 0):

Статистика из нацкорпуса:

```
Поскольку если
```

Запятая обычно не ставится.

```
То есть если ...
```

вроде 50 на 50.

```
..., что чтобы ...
```

тоже около 50 на 50.

Редки случаи **если** в качестве вводного предложения. Еще сложнее представить придаточное к союзу **то есть**, а не к **если**, со сменой смысла. То есть случаи, когда запятая регламентируется правилами, довольно редкие. Почему же тогда люди с 50% постоянством лепят запятые? Видимо, они делятся на два типа. Те, кто любит запятые и те, кто не любит.

Иногда мне хочется поставить запятую перед началом предложения просто потому, что его первая, придаточная часть звучит нелепо и надо бы начать со второй, но хочется выделить первую.

Сравните

```
Чтобы затем уйти, Михаил вернулся
Михаил вернулся, чтобы затем уйти.
```

В таких ситуациях союз перед предложением служит поводом для запятой перед придаточным:

```
И, чтобы затем уйти, Михаил вернулся.
И Михаил вернулся, чтобы затем уйти.
```

Comment: Языковая комбинаторика обширна, и никто никогда не регламентирует множество языковых ситуаций, которые к тому же будет генерироваться изменяющимся языком, — и люди в таких ситуациях будут писать как попало или исходя из каких-то своих принципов. Я, в таких ситуациях с «то есть», ставлю запятую, так как «то есть» относится к двум последующим подпредложениям одновременно, поясняя весь предыдущий текст, и, на мой взгляд, справделиво пунктуационно относить этот союз к главному предложению, а не придаточному.

Answer (score 0):

Без запятой получается такой смысл:
*То есть если хочешь стать испытателем, [но] сначала поработай обычным лётчиком.*
Так "то есть" относится к придаточному.