# Пунктуация: о правилах школьных и правилах «для взрослых»

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, правила

В школе я неплохо успевала по русскому языку, знала на приличном уровне правила, но иногда задумывалась вот над чем.

Как интересно расставлены знаки препинания в книгах – мне казалось, что в таких сложных  предложениях их сложно выбрать по обычным правилам. Должно быть, существуют другие правила – **не школьные, а «для взрослых».** И, наверное, они очень трудные, мне никогда так не научиться! Это особое мастерство.

И вот в ходе последней дискуссии мне вдруг ясно и сразу вспомнились эти рассуждения, до этого совершенно забытые.  Так что я узнала с тех пор? Оказывается, нет никаких правил «для взрослых» и всё должно писаться по одному и тому же **стандарту** – и школьные сочинения, и художественные романы!

И мне (именно мне, вот ведь личный парадокс!) приходится буквально  «сражаться» **за одну-единственную запятую**, которую писатель поставил по своему видению, по своему слуху.

Но почему! Почему у нас есть разнообразные **стили речи**, когда решаются совершенно **разные задачи**, а правила письма все те же – **"для школьников"**. Как такое  может быть?

**И вопросы:**

Нужно ли нам **два уровня правил**, базисный и расширенный?

А пока их нет, можно ли терпимее и с большим уважением относиться **к авторской пунктуации**,  в том числе **при анализе** художественных произведений на нашем форуме?  Я сейчас  подчеркиваю **практический** характер вопроса: следует ли нам критиковать классиков или будем объяснять их выбор?

Что мы демонстрируем, выражая свое неприятие авторских решений, – **хорошее знание** правил или свою **ограниченность** в этом плане?

По материалам вопроса [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464069/Запятая-после-то-есть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464069/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

P.S.  Вот такая «перекличка» времен… Я не планировала ни о чем спрашивать (вроде бы всё уже сказано), но будто кто-то положил передо мной лист бумаги и попросил: *запиши еще это*. Листок был совершенно чист, но я повиновалась. Пяти минут хватило для того, чтобы всё вспомнить и  записать текст. Положила ручку  и взглянула  в пространство – ответа не было, но  я всё-таки решила отправить  вопрос.  Для будущего, наверное.:)