# Запятая после «да»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после "да" в этом предложении?

***Да** если бы она умела говорить, она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной.*

Comment: https://classes.ru/context-russian-english-term-895874.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая после частицы ДА не ставится:
***Да если бы она умела говорить, она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной.***

Пояснение

**Из словаря:**  ДА, частица.  8. (в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.). Употр. для придания высказыванию **большей силы, выразительности.** И я чего-нибудь да стою! Да что с вами говорить! Да так оно обычно и бывает. Да кто вы такой, чтоб так задаваться?

Ответ ироничный, смысл его понятен. Родословная собаки настолько хороша, что она даже ни с кем и разговаривать бы не стала. В ответе использована гипербола —  художественный прием, основанный на преувеличении свойств и качеств.

Comment: Пусть не ставится, но где правило, которое позволяет не ставить запятую перед придаточным? Речь не об этой частице, а о всех, например: *ведь, ну, то есть*.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137  Пункт 6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то перед ними ставится запятая (вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается): Катя вышла из столовой, как раз когда мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы (Кав.); Я эту работу выполню, только если буду свободен

Comment: Эти частицы как раз к придаточному примыкают по структуре, но дальше сказано про *вот* и *ведь*, но нет обобщения насчёт всех частиц. Порой из-за отсутствия запятой может образовываться двусмысленность.

Comment: "ДА" в этом предложении усилительная частица? Усилительная вроде бы. Тогда какие вопросы? Или вы диссертацию по частицам собрались написать? :))

Comment: "Да" не относится к придаточному, как те частицы. Когда относится, можно главное предложение поставить перед придаточным. Кстати, у этих частиц похожее значение, такое же у "да", если её отнести к придаточному. Такой смысл получается: *только/лишь/исключительно если бы она умела говорить, она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной*.

Comment: Переставляете предложения в СПП, как ребенок кубики.  А вам известно, что позиция придаточного – это СТРУКТУРНЫЙ элемент СПП. В нормальной позиции придаточное стоит после главного, а у нас инверсированная позиция, в этом случае отношения не подчинительные, а взаимоподчиненные. И частица  ДА усиливает эти взаимоподчиненные отношения, то есть ВЗАИМНУЮ ОБУСЛОВЛЕННОСТЬ.  И это касается всех усилительных частиц, стоящих перед подчинительным союзом. Читайте матчасть, то есть Кустову :))  Найдите мне онлайн учебник Кустовой хотя бы 2013 года, а то 2005 год  иногда значительно отличается, пжста.

Comment: Перестановка используется у Розенталя, это серьёзная вещь, а не детская! С одними частицами возможны обе позиции, а с другими нет — тогда частица грамматически относится к главному. И это факт.

Comment: Нашёл: https://bunker4.zlibcdn.com/dtoken/e985d2cef89619300b1df5319aeaff0c Такие книги есть, а вот советские мало какие доступны (тот же Розенталь, к сожалению).

Comment: А как вы знаете, что он иногда значительно отличается, если у вас его нет?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ссылку, у меня был только бумажный вариант 2013 года.  Правда, со старого учебника 2005 года можно  было копировать текст, а здесь только  выделять фрагменты.  Ну, теперь на стр. 151 вы можете прочитать, что позиция придаточного –  это структурный элемент СПП и к нему надо относиться с уважением. А Розенталь использовал перестановку или для обучения серьезных детей младшего школьного возраста, или в условных целях для формализации (упрощения) правил. А вот с целью анализа, как в данном случае, использовать перестановку нужно с осторожностью.

Comment: Был и пропал? Розенталь говорил про перестановку всем, а не серьёзным детям. Это достойный метод.

Answer (score 2):

**В зависимости от интонации возможны варианты.**

**1.**

*– У вашей собаки хорошая родословная?*

*– У нее? Да если бы она умела говорить, она бы не стала разговаривать ни с вами, ни со мной!*

(Здесь «да» – частица, придающая высказыванию силу, выразительность.)

**2.**

*– У вашей собаки хорошая родословная?*

*– У нее? Да. Если бы она умела говорить, она бы не стала разговаривать ни с вами, ни со мной!*

(Здесь «да» – частица, употребляемая в качестве утвердительного ответа на заданный вопрос.)

Comment: Это понятно само собой. Речь о запятой перед придаточным. Какое правило позволяет её опускать? Усилительная частица относится к главному.

Comment: _oleedd: Это понятно само собой. Речь о запятой перед придаточным. Какое правило позволяет её опускать? Усилительная частица относится к главному._ === По-моему, не к главному. **Ко всему предложению!** (Она изменяет в рассматриваемом примере интонацию прочтения не только главного, но и придаточного, стоящего перед главным.)

Comment: Если так, то запятую на стыке союзов нужно тоже отменить, многие его нарушают.

Comment: А в каком правиле указано, что частицу можно относить ко всему предложению и можно не ставить запятую перед придаточным?

Answer (score 1):

Проверим, относится ли **усилительная** частица напрямую к придаточному:
*Она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной, да если бы она умела говорить.* || Нет, так не получается — значит, не относится, относится к главному:
*Да она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной.*

Нет правила, которое позволяет не ставить запятую (на общих основаниях) после любой частицы в таком случае. Хотя пауза там явно не делается.
Так что выбирайте: действовать по правилам или плюнуть на это и писать без запятой, потому что нет паузы (большинство делают так, [примеры](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%94%D0%B0+%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B5)).

По грамматическому принципу запятая нужна — так как "да" относится к главному, а не к придаточному.
По интонационному принципу не нужна — так как нет паузы и логического ударения на частице.
Всё-таки грамматический является ведущим.

Похожий вопрос:
[Запятая после "то есть"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464069)
Как там правильно заметил Alex_ander, чтобы показать смысл, когда запятая относится к придаточному, надо добавить "только":
*Да если бы только она умела говорить, [тогда] она бы не стала разговаривать ни с Вами, ни со мной.*