# Ведь(,) если звезды зажигают... Это авторская пунктуация?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

> Ведь(,) если звезды зажигают — значит — это кому-нибудь нужно?

Запятая после "ведь" — авторская пунктуация В. В. Маяковского?

Comment: Очень долго искал этот вопрос и всё-таки нашел: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468391 Там это обсуждали.

Comment: Ага! Спасибо! Надо вникнуть! У вас там очень высокий уровень обсуждения. Почему мне такой вопрос пришёл в голову? Да у Риммы Михайловой прочитала комментарий: "Но ведь если мы идем рядом с морем (вдоль набережной), мы разве не знаем, что морская вода является соленой? (Пресных морей не бывает.)"

Comment: В правилах будто боятся говорить о самом сложном, брать на себя ответственность. Об этом крайне мало сказано. Розенталь лаконично сказал, что не ставится, и перечислил всего лишь три частицы.

Comment: *является солёной* - не нравится мне это. Если являться, то не каким-то, а кем-то/чем-то. Пример: *Шар является синим.* Оно же не звучит, без существительного.

Comment: Да, в БТС тоже сказано *кем/чем*.

Comment: Это существительное (чем? — водой),  конечно же, подразумевается. Зачем нам повторы? Почему талая вода является идеально чистой [водой]. Найденная под Азовским морем вода является питьевой [водой]. Пресная вода является безопасной для здоровья человека. P. S. Господи, столько *копьев* из-за одного комментария.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что авторская. Маяковский руководствовался тем, что придаточное можно переставить.
Розенталь решил по-другому, наверное, потому, что большинство авторов не ставили запятую из-за отсутствия паузы.
Это две разные точки зрения, заслуживающие уважения.
А вот второе тире мне не нравится. Вводное слово по смыслу примыкает к главному предложению, а тире эту связь разрывает. Хотел паузу подлиннее, чтобы показать раздумье? Для этой цели используется многоточие, хоть оно там и не очень смотрится. Вставочной интонации там нет, а вставка сделана.

Comment: Либо там два интонационных тире подряд, но так никто не делает, потому что от вставки не отличить.

Comment: Кстати, мне удалось зарегистрироваться! Вами предложенный способ сработал вдруг. thx)

Comment: Да, догадался после лайков. Оно на странице профиля показывает. А какой? VPN?

Comment: Да нет. Просто темп-мэйл система приняла. А адреса других сервисов не принимала!

Comment: Странно это всё. Оно должно любой принимать. Ну или хоть сказать, какие запрещены.